# SharePoint JSON Formatter Boolean as Yes No

Tags: json, sharepoint, formatter

With JSON formatter, how do you make a the content of a boolean Yes No instead true false?

```
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"children": [{"elmType": "span",
        "style": {"display": "inline-block"}},
        {"elmType": "span", 
"txtContent": "@currentField"}]
```

With this the column values are showing as "true" and "false"

Answer (score 0):

Use the **displayValue** property to get the default rendered value of Yes/No column type:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [{"elmType": "span",
            "style": {"display": "inline-block"}},
            {"elmType": "span", 
    "txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue"}]
    }
```

Result:

[image]

More information for your reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#displayvalue